# Navigation links dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery

On https://bm-translations.de when I click on a link in navigation it doesnt link to the anchor (its doing nothing).

I can see the error in the console, but I really dont know how to fix it. Maybe you can give me any helping advice, why exactly this error occurs and where to start looking for a solution?

Maybe there is something to except the navigation links from all the javascript except 2 functions (one for smooth scrolling and one for changing active class)?

Comment: `I can see the error in the console` ... what error? don't expect people to click on your site - post a minimal example of your code if you want any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ("Syntax error, unrecognized expression: https://bm-translations.de/#sprachrichtungen") seems to be that in

```
//Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link
$(document).on("click", ".navbar-nav a", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $("html, body").animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $($.attr(this, "href")).offset().top
    },
    500
  );
});
```

you end up passing the full href `https://bm-translations.de/#sprachrichtungen` to `$()`.  You could parse out the hash part using `String.split()`, but the easier way is to use the [`.hash` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/hash) of `a` elements:

```
//Smooth scrolling when clicking an anchor link
$(document).on("click", ".navbar-nav a", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  $("html, body").animate(
    {
      scrollTop: $($.prop(this, "hash")).offset().top
    },
    500
  );
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: brilliant, now it works! Thank you so much! I will accept your answer in few minutes, when I am allowed to do.